# Сохранение объекта в базу данных с одинаковым полем

Tags: java, база-данных, алгоритм, многопоточность, любой-язык

Есть GWT приложение, которое отправляет асинхронный запрос на сервер. Сервер обращается к REST сервису для сохранения переданного объекта в базу данных (сохранение долгое около 10 секунд, база реляционная).

Перед началам сохранения мне нужно проверить есть ли в базе объект с таким же полем (например `Name`) и если нету то продолжить сохранение.

Что делать, если придет второй запрос - он пройдет валидацию, начнется сохранение, и окажется что поля `Name` совпадут (объект станет невалидным)?

Блокировать приложение на время сохранения не хочется. Стоит ли решать такую проблему или такая ситуация маловероятна? Какое есть решение для таких случаев?

**Мне нужно запретить сохранение эксперимента с уже существующим именем.**

Comment: "или такая ситуация маловероятна" - это известно только Вам. "Какое есть решение" - cделать запрос, проверяющий наличие записи и создающий запись, если ее нет, атомарной операцией.

Comment: Почему нельзя повесить `UNIQUE` на поле `name` в базе и обрабатывать исключение при неудаче?

Comment: То есть сделать атомарной я понимаю это заблокировать другие потоки до тех пор пока объект успешно не сохраниться, но как я сказал сохранение достаточно долгое и ждать я не могу. Изменять атрибуты полей я не могу, работаю с базой через REST сервис (запись/чтение).

Comment: Нет, это не то, что я хотел сказать. Долгое сохранение начинается, когда выясняется, что нет такого значения `Name`. Сделайте эту проверку и создание записи с `Name` атомарной операцией, а все остальное "сохранение" - нет.

Comment: довольно странно описана ситуация.. любое решение (два запроса - второй по результату первого или все реализовано в одном)  никак не отразится на пользовательском интерфейсе (если в нем принудительно не создается нечто, что показывает, что запрос в базу отрабатывается и на время отработки запроса возможности пользователя в интерфейсе ограничиваются).. если вызов реализуется стандартным AsynсCallback, то в принципе можно не ожидать ответа от сервера..

Comment: Возможна ситуация когда я проверю наличие эксперимента с таким именем и начну его сохранять. В этот момент придет другой запрос на сохранение эксперимента с таким же именем как и первый, В этом случае проверка на наличие такого же имени не даст результатов так как изменения от первого сохранения еще не будут видны. Возможно @Igor был прав и стоит сделать операции проверки и записи имени атомарными, останется только поделить сохранение эксперимента на части.